# How can I subtract an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The data in the MongoDB is like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b30d15d1e8b07d6a659ea81"), "group" : "2", "data" : { "count" : [  {  "f1" : 56,  "f2" : 48 },  {  "f1" : 95,  "f2" : 6 } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b30d1671e8b07d6a659ea82"), "group" : "3", "data" : { "count" : [  {  "f1" : 15,  "f2" : 72 },  {  "f1" : 56,  "f2" : 74 } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b30d1731e8b07d6a659ea83"), "group" : "4", "data" : { "count" : [  {  "f1" : 12,  "f2" : 96 },  {  "f1" : 85,  "f2" : 85 } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b30d17c1e8b07d6a659ea84"), "group" : "5", "data" : { "count" : [  {  "f1" : 73,  "f2" : 56 },  {  "f1" : 96,  "f2" : 79 } ] } }
```

I need to get the data where `f1 - f2 > 0`, which means I need the first and fourth records and filter out the second and third records. How can I do that?

Is there something similar to `db.events.find({"$and":[{"difference":{"$subtract":{"data.count.f1": "data.count.f2"}}}, {"difference": {"$gt": 0}}]})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator (found in versions 3.6 and above) as the `find()` method query expression, you can make use of the **[`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/)** operator which takes in an array as a set and returns true if any of the elements are true and false otherwise. An empty array returns false.

To produce the array with elements that evaluate to true or false based on the subtract logic above, use **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** to iterate over the count array and return the evaluated logic.

The following shows this in action:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find(
    {
        "$expr": {
            "$anyElementTrue": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$data.count",
                    "as": "count",
                    "in": { 
                        "$gt": [
                            { "$subtract": [ "$$count.f1", "$$count.f2" ] },
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                } }
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

---

For earlier versions you can use **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** as follows:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$anyElementTrue": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$data.count",
                            "as": "count",
                            "in": { 
                                "$gt": [
                                    { "$subtract": [ "$$count.f1", "$$count.f2" ] },
                                    0
                                ]
                            }
                        } }
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use aggregation for this, because `$subtract` can only be used within a `$project` stage
Here is the aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data.count"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "group": 1,
      "data": 1,
      "diff": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$data.count.f1",
          "$data.count.f2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "diff": {
        "$gt": 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/Jp_G6Q0y26Q](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jp_G6Q0y26Q)